# Pivot table with more than two foreign ids

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

So I have a table, **cities**

[image: City table]

Second table is **movies**,

[image]

And the third table is **theatres**

[image]

I have a **Pivot** table which connects all three of these.

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is, to get only those theatres where `city_id` and `movie_id` are a certain value.
This is my controller

```
class MovieController extends Controller
{
    public function test(){
        $city_id=1;
        $movie_id=1;
        $th=Movie::where('id',$movie_id)->first();
        dd($th->theatre);
    }
}
```

I want all the theatres where `movie_id=1` and `city_id=1`

**Movie Model**

```
class Movie extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function theatre(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Theatre::class,'city_movie_theatre');
    }
    public function city(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(City::class,'city_movie_theatre');
    }
}
```

Theatre Model

```
class Theatre extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function city(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(City::class,'city_movie_theatre');
    }
    public function movie(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Movie::class,'city_movie_theatre','theatre_id','movie_id');
    }
}
```

Pivot Table Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;
class City_Movie_Theatre extends Pivot
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table='city_movie_theatre';
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your threatre model, mention in city_id as pivot

```
class Theatre extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    ...

    public function movie(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Movie::class,'city_movie_theatre','theatre_id','movie_id')->withPivot('city_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Then put the where condition on your relation and on your pivot column

```
Theatre::whereHas('movie', function ($query) {
    return $query->where('movie_id', '=', 1);
})->wherePivot('city_id', '=', 1)->get();
```

If you want any dynamic value for movie_id then use `use($movie_id)` and put it in condition

```
$movie_id = $city_id = 1;
Theatre::whereHas('movie', function ($query) use($movie_id, $city_id){
    return $query->where('movie_id', '=', $movie_id);
})->wherePivot('city_id', '=', $city_id)->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use "relation" with a closure where you can define your matching condition.

```
Movie::with('theater', function($query) use ($theater_id, $city_id){
  $query->where('theater_id',$theater_id); 
  })->with('city', function($query) use ($city_id){
    $query->where('city_id',$city_id);})->get();
```

Comment: From where does `$theater_id` came?